# RSK and promotion

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory

Take a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ and let $P \times Q$ be
the pair of standard young tableaux with $n$ boxes associated to $\sigma$ under the Robinson-Schensted correspondence. Now perform the more general RSK-algorithm to the two-line array $\acute{\sigma}$ given by

\begin{equation} \acute{\sigma} \ = \
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & \cdots & {n-1} \\
\sigma(2) &\sigma(3) &\cdots &\sigma(n)  
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

and obtain a new pair of tableaux $\acute{P} \times \acute{Q}$
sharing a common shape with $n-1$ boxes. Note that the recording
tableau $\acute{Q}$ will be standard.

**Question:** Is it the case that $\acute{Q}$ coincides with the 
standard tableau obtained by applying Stanley's promotion operator to $Q$ and then subsequently removing the box labeled by $n$ ?

ines.

Comment: I don't have time to check this in all details, but I think your Question is a particular case of the Lemma in [Marc van Leeuwen, mathoverflow post #140739](https://mathoverflow.net/q/140739). Note that I am not sure what you mean by "Stanley's promotion operator": didn't Schuetzenberger invent promotion for tableaux, which (at least in the case of standard tableaux) Stanley then generalized to linear extensions of posets? Or is Schuetzenberger's promotion operator not actually what Schuetzenberger found?

Comment: You should define the promotion operator. There are maybe 250 people in the world who could look at this title and know what it means. darij and I are two of them, and we don't know off the top of our heads what the promotion operator is.

Comment: Dear Darij, Yes --- I mean Schützenberger promotion (and Stanley's generalisation of this notion to linear extensions of a finite poset). Upon first reading I'm not sure if van Leeuwen's lemma applies --- I'll look. Thanks ! best, Ines

Comment: I feel like this lemma Darij mentions will apply, since the promotion operator can be interpreted as applying a (edge of a) growth diagram, which is the same as jeu de taquin in this case.